# SQL select rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Oracle SQL Database with values like:

```
Date       Number    
20.04.22   1         
20.04.22   2 
20.04.22   3 
20.04.22   4 
20.04.22   5 
20.04.22   6 
21.04.22   1 
21.04.22   2 
21.04.22   3 
21.04.22   4
21.04.22   5 
21.04.22   6
```

Now, I want to select 3 rows, starting on number==value. The value is coming from somewhere else. For example, that value is 2, then I want to have 20.04.22 number 2-5.

How do I write a query if I want to have the numbers between two days? Like when the value is 6, then I need to have 20.04.22 number 6 and 21.04.22 number 1-2...

If its just one day, I can use where number >= [number i choose]

Thanks!

Comment: The _first_ thing you should do is stop using 2-digit years.  Is '21.04.22' supposed to be April 21, 2022, or April 22, 2021, or April 22, 1921, or  . . . or . . . or . . .  ?  I spent a big chunk of my life in 1998-1999 remediating for Y2k.  Please don't re-create it.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT "DATE", "NUMBER"
FROM   ( 
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(CASE "NUMBER" WHEN 6 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY "DATE", "NUMBER")
           AS cnt
  FROM   table_name t
  ORDER BY "DATE", "NUMBER"
)
WHERE cnt > 0
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

Before Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT "DATE", "NUMBER"
FROM   ( 
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(CASE "NUMBER" WHEN 6 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY "DATE", "NUMBER")
           AS cnt
  FROM   table_name t
  ORDER BY "DATE", "NUMBER"
)
WHERE cnt > 0
AND   ROWNUM <= 3;
```

*(Note: `DATE` and `NUMBER` are reserved words and it is considered bad practice to use them as identifiers and, if you do, then must be quoted identifiers.)*

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ("DATE", "NUMBER") AS
SELECT DATE '2022-04-20', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-20', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-20', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-20', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-20', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-20', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-21', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-21', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-21', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-21', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-21', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-04-21', 6 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DATE | NUMBER |
> | --- | --- |
> | 20-APR-22 | 6 |
> | 21-APR-22 | 1 |
> | 21-APR-22 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6f505c117d214746abcdd131a064dc0b)*